# Not able to see the whole page after launching the application in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

When I am trying to launch may application I am not able to se the the whole Page.I have added # button.but only two Buttons are visible.How should Make it comaptible with Emulator so that I can se whaever there in pages.

Here is the code:

This is my Xml File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.button.ButtonActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="This area is for you to administer the mulitple persons for which you are maintaining records." />



      <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:text="Add a new Person" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="Current Person" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Switch To Person" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Rename Person" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Delete This Person" />

    </RelativeLayout>

ManifestFile

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.button"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.button.ButtonActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please Suggest something..

Comment: remove `android:layout_marginTop="27dp"` from every `Button`

Comment: Try to add ScrollView as parent layout.

Comment: It will depend on screen size as you are not adding scroll view.
To see whole page on smallest screen size also you have to add scrollview at parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.button.ButtonActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewTopicGrade"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

        <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="This area is for you to administer the mulitple persons for which you are maintaining records." />



      <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:text="Add a new Person" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="Current Person" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Switch To Person" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Rename Person" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Delete This Person" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.button.ButtonActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="This area is for you to administer the mulitple persons for which you are maintaining records." />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:text="Add a new Person" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="Current Person" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Switch To Person" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Rename Person" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Delete This Person" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

1. Remove This :

   ```
   android:paddingBottom = "@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft = "@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight = "@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop = "@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   ```

Else add Scroll view to parent layout.